# Switch angularjs template based on type

Tags: json, angularjs, angularjs-directive

I'm showing a grid box based on data and based on property "type"

i'm trying to loop using ng-repeat and load templates based on "type"

For example we have type 1,2,3,4 and html files like 1.html,2.html,3.html,4.html

what is the best way to load the template url based on  "type" value,

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this would be to use $routeProvider, if i understand your question correctly some thing like this:

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/1', {
        templateUrl: '1.html',
        controller: 1Ctrl
    }).when('/2', {
        templateUrl: '2.html',
        controller: 2Ctrl
    }).when('/3', {
        templateUrl: '3.html',
        controller: 3Ctrl
    }).when('/4', {
        templateUrl: '4.html',
        controller: 4Ctrl
    }).otherwise({redirectTo: '/1'})
```

**Edit** Yes I understand that symbol names cant start with a number, however this was stubbed fro OP code specs in question.

Comment: Symbol names can't start with numbers

Comment: sorry for not being clear, i'm trying to put inside ng-repeat and load templates based on value

Comment: here this might help [https://coderwall.com/p/mgtrkg](https://coderwall.com/p/mgtrkg) I think this is similar to what you are wanting to accomplish. If this is not correct the other option is to write a custom directive that will change template on the property like [http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/](http://onehungrymind.com/angularjs-dynamic-templates/).